# Keep Thread alive (pthread, c)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have the following situation:

A Fortran program calls (`iso_c_binding`) a function (written in C) that starts a server (socket functions) via the `pthread_create` function. This server is supposed to keep running (waiting for connections) until a certain variable is set to `1`. The problem I have is that as soon as the function that starts the server returns (to the Fortran program) the server thread exits.
I am not sure how to handle the situation (have the server socket running till it gets the signal to stop).

Kind regards

(Code added)

fortran program

```
...
FUNCTION run_server(ServerRuns) bind(c,name='run_server')
 use iso_c_binding
 import :: c_int
 integer(kind=c_int) :: run_server
 integer(kind=c_int), value :: ServerRuns
END FUNCTION run_server
...
fserver = run_server(ServerRuns)
...
```

c run server code

```
int run_server(int cservrun){

  int err;
  pthread_t tid[1];
  int i = 0;

  if (cservrun != 0){
   printf("[error] Process already running.\n");
   return -1;
  }else{

    err = pthread_create(&(tid[0]), NULL, (void *)&server, NULL);

    if (err != 0){
      printf("[error] Can't create \"server\" thread");
      return -1;  
    }else{
      printf("Server running\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

c server code

```
int server(void){

 ...
 stop_serv = 0;

 while(stop_serv == 0){
   printf("Server loop\n");
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

   if (newsockfd < 0){ 
     printf("[error] on accept");
     return -1; 
   } 

   bzero(buffer,SOB);
   n = read(newsockfd,buffer,SOB-1);
   if (n < 0){ 
     printf("[error] reading from socket");
     return -1;
   }

   printf("Message: _%s_\n",buffer);

   close(newsockfd);

 }

 close(sockfd);
 cservrun = 0; 

 return 0;
 }
```

If I add a while(1) loop after the "Server running" statement in the "c run server code" (before the return 0) the server stays alive and keeps reading messages.
I have to say that I am not an expert neither in Fortran programming nor in C programming.

Comment: How do you exactly call it? Show the code. I have personally no problems with asynchronous I/O using pthreads from Fortran.

Comment: Try making the `while` loop volatile. `while(*(volatile int *)& stop_serv == 0)` or whatever type `stop_serv` is.

Comment: Hmm.. is the FORTRAN 'call' starting a new process for 'run_server'?

Comment: Making the while loop volatile sadly doesnt seem to change anything.

Comment: "*... the server thread exits.*": by which exit point?

Comment: @alk: I am not sure what to tell you. As soon as the run_server functions returns to Fortran the server thread just ends/gets stopped/killed. When I keep the run_server function running the server thread keeps running. I guess it has something to do with the way Fortran calls the c functions but I am really stuck here.

Comment: How are you building your program?  Have you got just -lpthread or a thread option as well?  Depends on your platform.  For x86 it is -mthreads, IA64 -pthread.  Check your gcc manual.

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with your case, but the prototype of the thread function should be `void* server(void *)`.

Comment: @cup: I think I use "-lpthread -pthread" but I have the program at work and I am not 100% sure. I have another program that is totally written in c and there I basically do the same. I wrote it just to understand the logic of the client/server thing. It starts the server with pthread_create and while it is running in the background I can keep working with the main program. In this case there is no problem. I really think it has something to do with the way how Fortran calls the c functions.

Comment: You have logging statements in the thread function: Which one do you see last before the thread exits?

Comment: @alk: I will check it on Monday. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @cup: Thanks for reminding me of the compiler options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I did some changes in the Makefile and I found out that I really missed the -pthread option. It is really weird that there were no error messages and that the thread was created at all. Thank you very much for all of your help! I really appreciate it.